# summarise() a subset of cases with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

The data:

```
structure(list(subjnum = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), expVers = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Angry", "Happy"), class = "factor"), 
    intendedSOA = c(1000L, 1000L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 50L), compatability = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Comp", "Incomp"), class = "factor"), 
    T1RT = c(229L, 229L, 277L, 277L, 280L, 280L), T2RT = c(791L, 
    791L, 563L, 563L, 760L, 760L), T1ACC = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), T2ACC = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to summarize columns T1RT, T2RT, T1ACC and T2ACC by their `mean()` and organize these values by the other other variables / factors in the data (subjnum, intendedSOA, compatability, expVers). However, summaries of the variables T1RT and T2RT summaries **should not** include trials where `T1ACC or T2ACC == 0`, but summaries of the varaibles T1ACC and T2ACC **should** include all values (no conditional summation). I tried to include an `if()` argument in `summarise()` by doing the following:

```
> backcomplong2 <- ACC %>%
+   select(subjnum, expVers,intendedSOA, compatability, T1RT, T2RT, T1ACC, T2ACC)%>%
+   group_by(subjnum, compatability, expVers, intendedSOA)%>%
+   summarise(T1RT = if(T1ACC == 1 && T2ACC == 1) round(mean(T1RT)), 
+             T2RT = if(T1ACC == 1 && T2ACC == 1) round(mean(T2RT)),
+             T1ACC = mean(T1ACC), 
+             T2ACC = mean(T2ACC))
```

But received this error:

```
Problem with `summarise()` input `T1RT`.
x Input `T1RT` must be a vector, not NULL.
i Input `T1RT` is `if (T1ACC == 1 && T2ACC == 1) round(mean(T1RT))`.
i The error occured in group 14: subjnum = 3, compatability = "Comp", expVers = "Happy", intendedSOA = 100.
```

****** note that that my reproducible data will not return the same error ********
The larger data, which i did not provide here because it's too large for pasting into this question with `dput()`, returns the error.

I think I'm using the `if()` statement incorrectly, perhaps I could try `if_else()` instead? Another work around would be to simply do `summarise()` two times, once for the RT's and again for ACC, but this is more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put an `if` to check for a condition but don't put an `else` and tell what needs to be done when the condition is not satisfied. Hence, it returns a `NULL` object which results in an error.

You don't need `if`/`else` here though if you subset only those values which you want to take `mean` of. Try this :

```
library(dplyr)

ACC %>%
   group_by(subjnum, compatability, expVers, intendedSOA)%>%
   summarise(T1RT = mean(T1RT[T1ACC == 1 & T2ACC == 1]), 
             T2RT =  mean(T2RT[T1ACC == 1 & T2ACC == 1]),
             T1ACC = mean(T1ACC), 
             T2ACC = mean(T2ACC))
```

Comment: very easy, thank you very much! Your solution just subsets the T1RT.